# After each restart new iTerm window hangs for 5s on "xcode-build license check" [Apple M1]

Tags: xcode, big-sur, iterm, license

This is really annoying and I'd understand if this was due to a system update,
however after each restart a new iTerm window basically evaluates `xcode-build license check` for about 5s. Is there a way to turn it off?
I've tried `sudo xcodebuild -license accept`, but it seems to be unrelated to this issue.

I'm running Big Sur under Apple M1.

Comment: Undo whatever you added to the init for whichever shell you think you are using.

Comment: @MarcWilson Already did. .zshrc, .profile don't look suspicious, where else do I look?

Comment: No need to look anywhere else.  Add **all** the contents of your shell init to the question.  Also test and see if the shell does the same thing with Terminal.app.